# Как получать координаты в потоке?

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение в нём через google api client получаю данные о моём местоположении, если точнее — широту и долготу. Можно ли это делать в потоке или Google уже об этом побеспокоился?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что "делать в потоке" - это получать данные о местоположении в фоновом (не UI) потоке?

Comment: tse Да именно вы прав